# Displaying a web Page's Content on my Webpage which has my custom JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I want to Display the content of a webpage ( say wikipedia ) on my web page which has my custom JavaScript how shall i do that ?

I tried to use the iFrame for this but the JavaScript that i have on my page doesnt work on the Iframe but it does work on the rest of the body

How should i use the content of a different webpage on my webpage so that i can use my JavaScript on that page.

I want a page like google translator which has on top my Header and on the bottom the content of a webpage.

is it done through an iFrame or a content placeholder or ... what ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to fetch the content from your **server**, build up a page around it (possibly using an `<iframe>`; that'd certainly be the simplest thing) and then serve it up.  There might be all sorts of problems as the page tries to fetch its auxiliary files (CSS, scripts, images) because it may use relative URLs. Depending on what you know about the remote page, you'd have to do some surgery on the fetched content before sending it out to the client.

You cannot mess with content fetched from a different domain.  That's why it doesn't work when you just include a frame that directly fetches the other content from the client. When you fetch the content from your server, however, the browser will be happy.

Oh, and also, note that forms or AJAX code in the fetched content may also have problems when running inside your site, because again it may use relative URLs. Even if it isn't, you may have security problems, because there's no way for a user to really log in (unless you proxy that too from your server).

Comment: I want a googletraslator type of site. which has a frame on top and the content below. when i click the content then the content is copied on to my clipboard.  For example ( the wikipedia page is loaded and when i select a text it gets loaded into a variable through javascript ) i can perform this on a normal webpage although ti cant do this on a page that is called on a iFrame .

Comment: But the Url that i am having is on a Different domain... What tricks of the trade can i apply for that type of conditions ?

Comment: That's what my answer explains: you have to fetch the content *at your server*, and then forward it out to the client.

Comment: But i dont know  how to use this file . i am sure its something like this...


<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>

Comment: <div id="content"> <?php
$homepage = file_get_contents($_POST["LINK"]);
echo $homepage;
?></div>


this code made it work... but the Css wont be pucked up by this... how can i call the css too?

Comment: Well I think it's a difficult thing to do, as you seem to realize. If you think about it, how often do you see this done on the Internet? Is there any other website that does what you want to do?  Re-using content from other sites is kind-of hard, and generally people like it that way.

Comment: Yah... Its kind of hard but i wanted to  try it. I want to "cache" the pages along with the CSS. The file_get_contents functions gets the content but doesnt get the CSS .

Any ideas how can i get the CSS along with the file ? :)